# Can an orienteering compass be used in place of a protractor?

Tags: navigation, flight-simulator

First off, please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I was given a protractor during flight training, learnt to use it and obviously works quite well.

However, I've started using my old maps for sim use and used an orienteering compass which also works quite well

In fact, I found it easier to get bearings using the compass than the protractor.

So for my question, has a protractor always been issued and used, or do some schools prefer to use other orientation tools?

[image: Aviation Protractor]
[image: Orienteering Compass]

Comment: I'm not understanding how you are using the orienteering compass, could you explain more fully? Are you actually aligning the chart north with it?

Comment: @GdD No, the compass has meridian lines similar to the protractor.

Answer (score 1):

From your description you are using the orienteering compass to measure course lines by aligning the side of the compass to the grid lines and using the dial to align with the course. There's no thing inherently wrong with this method, if done properly it will give you an accurate course. Personally I like the protractor better, but it is personal choice. You may have to explain what you're doing to an examiner later, I wouldn't imagine it would be disqualifying though, although you never know, some examiners are sticklers for that kind of thing.

However, before you throw away the protractor I suggest you put one hand behind your back and try to use your orienteering compass to measure a course. You see, at least in the UK you will be tested on your ability to divert, measuring a course using a map while also flying the airplane. That's where that kind of protractor comes into its own, and why I'd recommend you stick with it.

Comment: I get the true course to waypoint by lining the edge of the compass with my desired track then turn the compass dial so that meridian lines are parallel, then reading the indicated course. I'm not discarding the protractor, just found it interesting that I was easier to read bearings from

Comment: @chaos505 - You've re-invented the [rotating plotter](https://www.asa2fly.com/Ultimate-Rotating-Plotter-P69.aspx).